# Не правильно работает анимация UIView

Tags: ios, swift, анимация, uiview

Писал змейку. Согласно документации, при длительности анимации <=0, анимации не происходит. Но она анимируется.

```
let dur = abroad ? -1 : speed
UIView.animate(withDuration: dur) {
        for i in 0..<(self.snakes.count - 1) {
            let snake = self.snakes[self.snakes.count - i - 2]
            let temp = oldFrame
            oldFrame = snake.frame
            snake.frame = temp
            if snake.frame.intersects(main.frame) {
                self.gameOver = true
                print("game over!!!!!")
            }
        }
        if self.abroad {
            print(dur) // -1
        }
    }
```

Причем когда делаю вот так

```
var dur:TimeInterval = 0
```

анимации нету, а когда вот так:

```
var dur:TimeInterval = 0
if !abroad {
    dur = TimeInterval(speed)
}
```

анимация происходит и тогда, когда abroad == false.
Не могу понять в чем дело. Заранее спасибо за помощь

Comment: в документации сказано  `If you specify a negative value or 0, the changes are made without animating them`, то есть изменения все равно будут происходить, но без анимации, возможно это и происходит

Comment: @schmidt9 мне это и нужно, чтобы изменения происходили, но без анимации. а он изменяет с анимацией

Comment: `анимация происходит и тогда, когда abroad == false` - так у вас тогда происходит `dur = TimeInterval(speed)`, при этом `speed` как я понимаю не равен нулю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подтверждаю несоответствие поведению, указанному в [документации](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622418-animate) к `animate(withDuration:animations:)` по крайней мере при проверке на iOS 13.5

> **duration**
>
> The total duration of the animations, measured in seconds. If you specify a negative value or 0, the changes are made without animating
> them.

В следующем примере анимация происходит при значении меньше нуля, **но** ее нет при значении равном нулю (`let duration: TimeInterval = 0`)

**Решение**: использовать 0 для отключения анимации

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!

    @IBAction func buttonTouchUpInside(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let duration: TimeInterval = -1 // assign 0 to disable animation
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration) {
            self.label.frame = self.label.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: 300)
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: я изначально использовал с 0, с нулем тоже не правильное поведение

Comment: @Hrayr попробуйте мой пример

Comment: с вашим кодом при значении 0 анимации нет. но с моим она все еще есть(

Comment: @Hrayr значит возможно дело в вашем коде? Попробуйте максимально упростить его, пока не заработает. Или дополните свой вопрос кодом, чтобы его можно было проверить